# Finding a subsequence in longer sequence

Tags: c#

I need to find a sequence in other large sequence, for example, `{1,3,2,3}` is present in `{1,3,2,3,4,3}` and `{5,1,3,2,3}`. Is there any way to do it quickly with `IEnumerable` or with something else?

Comment: Is the sequence in an int array, or just a comma delimited string?

Comment: In fact it is a list<int> which can be converted to array.

Comment: Do you want to just check whether a subsequence is in a sequence and return true/false?

Comment: Yes just to check whether its present or not, and returning true/false.

Comment: I note that you are using the word "subsequence" in a sense more strict than the common definition. A subsequence is usually defined as a sequence formed by removing elements from another sequence without reordering the original sequence. You are actually looking for a *substring* -- though of course it is very uncommon these days to use "string" to mean anything other than a sequence of *characters*.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to @dlev's but this also handles `{1,1,1,2}.ContainsSubsequence({1,1,2})`

```
public static bool ContainsSubsequence<T>(this IEnumerable<T> parent, IEnumerable<T> target)
{
    var pattern = target.ToArray();
    var source = new LinkedList<T>();
    foreach (var element in parent) 
    {
        source.AddLast(element);
        if(source.Count == pattern.Length)
        {
            if(source.SequenceEqual(pattern))
                return true;
            source.RemoveFirst();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: An important subtlety in this implementation is that it only enumerates over each passed-in collection once, making the method internally consistent if it is invoked with collections whose enumeration order is non-deterministic.  Also note that a Queue<T> could be used in place of the linked list.

Answer (score 5):

This method will find a subsequence within a parent sequence, of any type that can be compared via `Equals()`:

```
public static bool ContainsSubequence<T>(this IEnumerable<T> parent, IEnumerable<T> target)
{
    bool foundOneMatch = false;
    using (IEnumerator<T> parentEnum = parent.GetEnumerator())
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> targetEnum = target.GetEnumerator())
        {
            // Get the first target instance; empty sequences are trivially contained
            if (!targetEnum.MoveNext())
                return true;

            while (parentEnum.MoveNext())
            {
                if (targetEnum.Current.Equals(parentEnum.Current))
                {
                    // Match, so move the target enum forward
                    foundOneMatch = true;
                    if (!targetEnum.MoveNext())
                    {
                        // We went through the entire target, so we have a match
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else if (foundOneMatch)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
bool match = new[] {1, 2, 3}.ContainsSubsequence(new[] {1, 2}); // match == true
match = new[] {1, 2, 3}.ContainsSubsequence(new[] {1, 3}); // match == false
```

Note that it assumes the target sequence has no `null` elements.

**Update**: Thanks for the upvotes, everyone, but there is actually a **bug** in the above code! If a partial match is found, but then doesn't turn into a full match, the process is *ended*, rather than reset (which is obviously incorrected when applied to something like `{1, 2, 1, 2, 3}.ContainsSubsequence({1, 2, 3})`).

The above code works really well for the more common definition of subsequence (i.e. contiguousness is not required) but in order to handle resetting (which most `IEnumerators` do not support) the target sequence needs to be enumerated up front. That leads to the following code:

```
public static bool ContainsSubequence<T>(this IEnumerable<T> parent, IEnumerable<T> target)
{
    bool foundOneMatch = false;
    var enumeratedTarget = target.ToList();
    int enumPos = 0;

    using (IEnumerator<T> parentEnum = parent.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (parentEnum.MoveNext())
        {
            if (enumeratedTarget[enumPos].Equals(parentEnum.Current))
            {
                // Match, so move the target enum forward
                foundOneMatch = true;
                if (enumPos == enumeratedTarget.Count - 1)
                {
                    // We went through the entire target, so we have a match
                    return true;
                }

                enumPos++;
            }
            else if (foundOneMatch)
            {
                foundOneMatch = false;
                enumPos = 0;

                if (enumeratedTarget[enumPos].Equals(parentEnum.Current))
                {
                    foundOneMatch = true;
                    enumPos++;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This code doesn't have any bugs, but won't work well for large (or infinite) sequences.

Comment: Did you make a mistake in your example? How is 1, 3 a sequence in 1, 2, 3? Both numbers exist, but not in sequence. It seems like your method determines whether numbers exist, without regard for order or sequence.

Comment: @James As I mention at the end, it allows for non-contiguous subsequences (so for example, `{1, 2, 3}.ContainsSubequence({2, 1, 3}) == false`.) As I also mention at the end, that condition is easily imposed, should that be required. Usually when talking about subsequences, contiguousness is *not* required (see, for example, the longest common subsequence problem.)

Comment: It should not allow for non-contiguous subsequences.

Comment: @dlev The following test seem to fail `{1,1,1,2}.ContainsSubsequence({1,1,2}) == true`. It is hard to make this test without making two arrays of the two enumerables.

Comment: @erikH, you are right. The algo needs to re-wind parentEnum to the the next element after the last partial match.

Comment: I believe an optimal answer would be based on [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) or [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm), and example of which is in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54309797/659190).

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a well studied problem and according to my research there are two algorithms that are [optimal for this job, depending on your data](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9635/an-example-where-knuth-morris-pratt-algorithm-is-faster-than-boyer-moore/10661).

Namely, they are the [**K**nuth-**M**orris-**P**ratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm and the [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) algorithm.

Here, I submit [my implementation of the KMP algorithm, originally reviewed here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211683/improved-knuth-morris-pratt-over-a-source-of-indeterminate-length).

Its written to handle a source or parent sequence of indeterminate length up to [`Int64.MaxValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2).

As we can see, the internal implementation returns a sequence of the indices at which the sub-string or target pattern occurs. You can present these results through your choice of facade.

You could use this simply like this,

```
var contains = new[] { 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3 }.Contains(new[] { 1, 3, 2, 3 });
```

[Here is a working fiddle that shows the code in action](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XPJgCC).

Below, follows the fully commented code for my answer.

```
namespace Code
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    /// <summary>
    /// A generic implementation of the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm that searches,
    /// in a memory efficient way, over a given <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static class KMP
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether a sequence contains the search string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">
        /// The type of elements of <paramref name="source"/>
        /// </typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">
        /// A sequence of elements
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="pattern">The search string.</param>
        /// <param name="equalityComparer">
        /// Determines whether the sequence contains a specified element.
        /// If <c>null</c>
        /// <see cref="EqualityComparer{T}.Default"/> will be used.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// <c>true</c> if the source contains the specified pattern;
        /// otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">pattern</exception>
        public static bool Contains<T>(
                this IEnumerable<T> source,
                IEnumerable<T> pattern,
                IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer = null)
        {
            if (pattern == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pattern));
            }

            equalityComparer = equalityComparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

            return SearchImplementation(source, pattern, equalityComparer).Any();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<long> IndicesOf<T>(
                this IEnumerable<T> source,
                IEnumerable<T> pattern,
                IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer = null)
        {
            if (pattern == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pattern));
            }

            equalityComparer = equalityComparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

            return SearchImplementation(source, pattern, equalityComparer);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies indices of a pattern string in a given sequence.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">
        /// The type of elements of <paramref name="source"/>
        /// </typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">
        /// The sequence to search.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="patternString">
        /// The string to find in the sequence.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="equalityComparer">
        /// Determines whether the sequence contains a specified element.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// A sequence of indices where the pattern can be found
        /// in the source.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
        /// patternSequence - The pattern must contain 1 or more elements.
        /// </exception>
        private static IEnumerable<long> SearchImplementation<T>(
            IEnumerable<T> source,
            IEnumerable<T> patternString,
            IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer)
        {
            // Pre-process the pattern
            (var slide, var pattern) = GetSlide(patternString, equalityComparer);
            var patternLength = pattern.Count;

            if (patternLength == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                    nameof(patternString),
                    "The pattern must contain 1 or more elements.");
            }

            var buffer = new Dictionary<long, T>(patternLength);
            var more = true;

            long sourceIndex = 0; // index for source
            int patternIndex = 0; // index for pattern

            using(var sourceEnumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
            while (more)
            {
                more = FillBuffer(
                        buffer,
                        sourceEnumerator,
                        sourceIndex,
                        patternLength,
                        out T t);

                if (equalityComparer.Equals(pattern[patternIndex], t))
                {
                    patternIndex++;
                    sourceIndex++;

                    more = FillBuffer(
                        buffer,
                        sourceEnumerator,
                        sourceIndex,
                        patternLength,
                        out t);
                }

                if (patternIndex == patternLength)
                {
                    yield return sourceIndex - patternIndex;
                    patternIndex = slide[patternIndex - 1];
                }
                else if (more && !equalityComparer.Equals(pattern[patternIndex], t))
                {
                    if (patternIndex != 0)
                    {
                        patternIndex = slide[patternIndex - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sourceIndex = sourceIndex + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Services the buffer and retrieves the value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The buffer is used so that it is not necessary to hold the
        /// entire source in memory.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <typeparam name="T">
        /// The type of elements of <paramref name="source"/>.
        /// </typeparam>
        /// <param name="buffer">The buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="source">The source enumerator.</param>
        /// <param name="sourceIndex">The element index to retrieve.</param>
        /// <param name="patternLength">Length of the search string.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The element value retrieved from the source.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// <c>true</c> if there is potentially more data to process;
        /// otherwise <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        private static bool FillBuffer<T>(
            IDictionary<long, T> buffer,
            IEnumerator<T> source,
            long sourceIndex,
            int patternLength,
            out T value)
        {
            bool more = true;
            if (!buffer.TryGetValue(sourceIndex, out value))
            {
                more = source.MoveNext();
                if (more)
                {
                    value = source.Current;
                    buffer.Remove(sourceIndex - patternLength);
                    buffer.Add(sourceIndex, value);
                }
            }

            return more;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the offset array which acts as a slide rule for the KMP algorithm.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">
        /// The type of elements of <paramref name="source"/>.
        /// </typeparam>
        /// <param name="pattern">The search string.</param>
        /// <param name="equalityComparer">
        /// Determines whether the sequence contains a specified element.
        /// If <c>null</c>
        /// <see cref="EqualityComparer{T}.Default"/> will be used.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>A tuple of the offsets and the enumerated pattern.</returns>
        private static (IReadOnlyList<int> Slide, IReadOnlyList<T> Pattern) GetSlide<T>(
                IEnumerable<T> pattern,
                IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer)
        {
            var patternList = pattern.ToList();
            var slide = new int[patternList.Count];

            int length = 0;
            int patternIndex = 1;

            while (patternIndex < patternList.Count)
            {
                if (equalityComparer.Equals(
                        patternList[patternIndex],
                        patternList[length]))
                {
                    length++;
                    slide[patternIndex] = length;
                    patternIndex++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (length != 0)
                    {
                        length = slide[length - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        slide[patternIndex] = length;
                        patternIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }

            return (slide, patternList);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to get you started. Once you've converted this list to a string, you can find the sequence using the substring:

```
if (String.Join(",", numericList.ConvertAll<string>(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())
{
    //get sequence
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function checks whether List `parent` contains List `target` using some LINQ:

```
    public static bool ContainsSequence<T>(this List<T> parent, List<T> target)
    {
        for (int fromElement = parent.IndexOf(target.First());
            (fromElement != -1) && (fromElement <= parent.Count - target.Count);
            fromElement = parent.FindIndex(fromElement + 1, p => p.Equals(target.First())))
        {
            var comparedSequence = parent.Skip(fromElement).Take(target.Count);
            if (comparedSequence.SequenceEqual(target)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
var a1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var a2 = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4 };

int index = -1;
bool res = a2.All(
    x => index != -1 ? (++index == a1.IndexOf(x)) : ((index = a1.IndexOf(x)) != -1)
);
```

Comment: Your solution seems the most elegant but try it with `a1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` and `a2 = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4 }` instead; also try if `a1` contains itself with this new value - it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling simple serializable types, you can do that quite easily if you convert the arrays to string:

```
public static bool ContainsList<T>(this List<T> containingList, List<T> containedList)
{
    string strContaining = "," + string.Join(",", containingList) + ",";
    string strContained = "," + string.Join(",", containedList) + ",";
    return strContaining.Contains(strContained);
}
```

Note that's an extension method, so you will be able to call it like:

```
if (bigList.ContainsList(smallList))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example with daily work, so far, without problems. I just iterate over a fairly long sequence, looking for matches for a given sub sequence.

```
static bool SubSequenceExist(byte[] longSeq, byte[] subseq)
    {
        int seq = longSeq.Length;
        int seqToFindLen = subseq.Length;
        int seqMatchCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < seq; i++)
        {
            if (longSeq[i] == subseq[seqMatchCount])
                seqMatchCount++;
            else
                seqMatchCount = 0;

            if (seqMatchCount == seqToFindLen) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```