# How to check whether a list is consecutive subset of another list

Tags: c#, list, subset

I have two list like this:

```
a1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
a2 = { 1, 3};
```

I want to check whether `a2` is a consecutive subset of `a1`. I use:

```
bool isSubset = !a2.Except(a1).Any();
```

Based on that example, `isSubset` should be `false`, but when I run, `isSubset = true`.

Comment: A set is unordered, so it is not what you are looking for. What you are looking for is basically the same as searching for a substring in a string. Look into string matching algorithms, that should give you an idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Could this ever happen in your system:

```
a1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 5};
a2 = { 1, 3};
```

Or is this not possible?

Also look at this:

[Finding a subsequence in longer sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324177/finding-a-subsequence-in-longer-sequence)

also, F# would be a *much* neater language for solving this kind of problem.

Comment: each of list is unique, so that condition is not possible. Now I already can solve that problem, but my another problem is how to know the number. i.e. based on that example, subset = {1,3}