# Find String Array in other String Array

Tags: c#

I want find a string array in other string array. How I do that?

Example:

```
string[] a = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","c","d","e"}

string[] b = {"d","e"}
```

How find `b` in `a`, I need get the index of all instances.

Comment: what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Upvoted - SO can be a mean place the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324177/) has 9 upvotes and here a new member gets clubbed to the ground.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you search a bit of the documentation to understand more of the language but anyway I'll try to explain what you can do

You can do a for loop going through the a array and inside you do a for loop going through the b array, if a[index] = b[index2] you break out of the a loop and put the index in a new array that you initialized before

If you need more help than that say but I recommend going through more documentation and a few videos and learn a bit more the basics