# Check if a list appear consecutively in any of the given lists

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have a main list:

```
public List<List<string>> validOrders = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06" },
    new List<string> { "02", "03", "01", "04", "05", "06" },
    new List<string> { "02", "03", "04", "01", "05", "06" },
};
```

and then I have another list :

```
public List<string> childObjectsPrefix = new List<string>();
```

Now I want to compare childObjectsPrefix with validOrders lists and check if the starting set appears consecutively in any of validOrders list.

Lets say my usecases are this way:

```
List<string> test1 = new List<string> { "01", "04" }; // False
List<string> test2 = new List<string> { "01", "02" }; // True
List<string> test3 = new List<string> { "02", "01" }; // False
List<string> test4 = new List<string> { "02", "03", "01" }; // True
List<string> test5 = new List<string> { "02", "03", "05" }; // False
```

I know how to check a subset of a list which is fairly straightforward but this is bit tricky.

Comment: Could you just concatenate all the strings and do Strings.Contains?

Comment: Strings.Contains will output true because both 01 and 04 are in the list, however I want to check if they appear consecutively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324177/finding-a-subsequence-in-longer-sequence

Comment: @MatthewWatson not really, because here I have { "01", "04" } and in validOrders[1] they appear consecutively but it ignores the previous values. I am checking for childObjectsPrefix[0] and [1]

Comment: `"020301040506".Contains("0104")` = true, and `"010203040506".Contains("0104")` = false, as you would expected, right? Ofc, this approach is only possible if you have some prior knowledge about what the strings may contain.

Comment: But it sounds like you want to check if  a string is a *prefix* to another, not "consecutively". In that case you could still use the string concatenation approach, just use `StartsWith` instead of contains.

Comment: You asked this yesterday, please dont just post again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this for consecutivly:

```
public static bool IsConsecutiveSubset(List<List<string>> validOrders, List<string> childObjectsPrefix)
{
    foreach (var validOrder in validOrders)
    {
        if (validOrder.Count < childObjectsPrefix.Count)
            continue; // Skip if the sublist is shorter than childObjectsPrefix

        for (int i = 0; i <= validOrder.Count - childObjectsPrefix.Count; i++)
        {
            if (childObjectsPrefix.SequenceEqual(validOrder.GetRange(i, childObjectsPrefix.Count)))
                return true; // Found a match
        }
    }

    return false; // No consecutive subset found
}
```

this code for start:

```
public static bool StartsWithPrefix(List<List<string>> validOrders, List<string> childObjectsPrefix)
{
    foreach (var validOrder in validOrders)
    {
        if (validOrder.Count < childObjectsPrefix.Count)
            continue; // Skip if the sublist is shorter than childObjectsPrefix

        if (validOrder.Take(childObjectsPrefix.Count).SequenceEqual(childObjectsPrefix))
            return true; // Found a match
    }

    return false; // No valid start found
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but unfortunately it outputs { "01", "04" } as true. Which is wrong because the list does not start with those strings.

Comment: Start isnt consecutivly.... then i edit the response

Comment: yeah sorry i meant start as.

Comment: Thank you that worked! :) Thanks for the quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

In *general case* (*arbitrary* types, *long* collections) we can use [Knuth Morris Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) for this, note that if items of a list are treated as "letters"
we are looking for a "substring" within "strings".

i.e. we can build KMP array:

```
private static int[] KmpArray<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence, 
                                 IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default) {
  if (sequence is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sequence));

  comparer ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

  IReadOnlyList<T> pattern = sequence as IReadOnlyList<T> ?? sequence.ToList();

  int[] result = new int[pattern.Count];

  int length = 0;
  int current = 1;

  while (current < pattern.Count)
    if (comparer.Equals(pattern[current], pattern[length]))
      result[current++] = ++length;
    else if (length != 0)
      length = result[length - 1];
    else
      result[current++] = length;

   return result;
}
```

and then use it

```
public static IEnumerable<int> IndexesOf<T>(IEnumerable<T> source,
                                            IEnumerable<T> pattern,
                                            IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = default) {
  if (source is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
  if (pattern is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pattern));

  IReadOnlyList<T> pat = pattern as IReadOnlyList<T> ?? pattern.ToList();

  if (pat.Count == 0)
    yield break;

  int[] lps = KmpArray(pat);

  comparer ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;

  using var en = source.GetEnumerator();

  for (bool agenda = en.MoveNext(); agenda;) {
    if (comparer.Equals(pat[j], en.Current)) {
      i += 1;
      j += 1;

      agenda = en.MoveNext();
    }

    if (j == pat.Count) {
      yield return i - j;

      j = lps[j - 1];
    }
    else if (agenda && !comparer.Equals(pat[j], en.Current)) {
      if (j != 0)
        j = lps[j - 1];
      else {
        i += 1;

        agenda = en.MoveNext();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Having this done all we should put is a simple Linq:

```
var order = new List<string> { "01", "02" };

bool result = validOrders.Any(item => IndexesOf(item, order).Any());
```